# Result from pipelined function, always will sorted as "written", or not?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Needed get renumbered result set, for example:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nums_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_series(from_n INTEGER, to_n INTEGER, cycle_max INTEGER)
  RETURN nums_list PIPELINED AS  
      cycle_iteration INTEGER := from_n;
  BEGIN
      FOR i IN from_n..to_n LOOP
          PIPE ROW( cycle_iteration );
          cycle_iteration := cycle_iteration + 1;
          IF cycle_iteration > cycle_max THEN
             cycle_iteration := from_n;
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN; 
  END;

  SELECT * FROM TABLE(generate_series(1,10,3));
```

Question is: there is guarantee, that oracle always will return result in that order? :

`1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1`

or maybe sometimes result will unexpected ordered, like this:

`1
1
1
1
2
2
....`

?

Comment: The data you will see is random sort, unless you add "order by"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pipelining **negates the need to build huge collections** by piping rows
>   out of the function as they are created, saving memory and allowing
>   subsequent processing to start before all the rows are generated

[pipelined-table-functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions)

This means, it will start processing the rows before get fetched completely and that's why you are seeing unpredictable order.